# Restore window to normal doesn't work after maximized in qt on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: qt, ubuntu

I meet two problems, I searched, but they seems not so easy as I think.
I'm working on ubuntu-18.04 with qt-5.15.x. And my two problems are:

1. cannot restore my window after maximizing it.
2. cannot move my window out of my screen with mouse dragging

**Can not restore**

Firstly, I set my window frameless, and then using a button standing for `maximize` or `restore`operations to trigger maximization or normal

```
// set fremeless in contruction
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | windowFlags());

// maximaization slot or restore
void WindowTitle::onButtonMaxClicked()
{
  QWidget *pWin = window();
  if(pWin->isMaximized())
  {
    pWin->showNormal();
  }
  else
  {
    pWin->showMaximized();
  }
}
```

What I expected is when I click button ,window will maximized, and that is true indeed. Then clicking on button again, window will return original position and size again, but that doesn't happen, instead, window's height is correct, but its width is equal screen(getting rid of applications docker bar), x-axis value is wrong too. And I have tried `setGeometry` after I have stored its value, but failed.

**Can not move outside**
I can make sure that I have set correct position with

```
void WindowTitle::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
  if (m_isPressed)
  {
    QPoint movePoint = event->globalPos() - m_startMovePos;
    QPoint widgetPos = QApplication::activeWindow()->pos();
    m_startMovePos = event->globalPos();
    QApplication::activeWindow()->move(widgetPos.x() + movePoint.x(), widgetPos.y() + movePoint.y());
  }
  return QWidget::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

function, but the result shows something wrong.

I have searched above two questions. But get nothing. And I'm curious that other applications can do just right both `restore` and `move`, suchlike `Firefox` web browser(which I'm typing on). So, there must be some way to make it work.

Comment: Use `QWidget::setGeometry` in addition to what you have as long as frameless window no longer driven by the OS so it is not really Ubuntu certain version problem. In Windows doing such thing also causes similar problems.

Comment: It's really frustrating. Are there any solutions? How do other apps, which reside in the same device and OS, solve these two problems?

Comment: I did code likes that saved QRect from QWidget::geometry() and then set it back with above. The whole exercise will just take a bit of time but that will work again, I am sure. Also read on whether event is coming from the system or from the user. What's the word...